# Using \cdots in Table - error: Missing $ inserted

Tags: tables, math-mode

Am getting countless error messages for 'Missing `$`'  and Extra `}`, or 'forgotten `$`'.
I am building a table and trying to fill some cells with dots (`\cdots`, `\vdots` etc). The first line in the table with errors is this one - I have defined 7 columns.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\caption[Matrix of Demand projections]{Matrix of demandssss.}
\begin{large}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c||c c c c c|} 
\hline
%First row - with errors below
& States \emph{G} & $\ g_{1}$ & \cdots & $\ g_{z}$ & \cdots & $\ g_{Z}$\\
```

The table constructs correctly, however I am getting loads of error messages. If anyone could help me understand why that'd be appreciated! Error messages are as follows:

```
Missing $ inserted
Extra }, or forgotten $.
Missing $ inserted
Missing } inserted
```

.. and so on... repeating itself as it tries to work it out.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\cdots` is a math mode command, hence the error. In text mode, use `\ldots`.

But better yet, use neither. Instead, use the `\dots` command indiscriminately (i.e. both in text mode and in math mode). The command requires the `amsmath` package. `\dots` also has the advantage of doing the right thing in different math contexts (meaning it adjusts its height automatically to fit surrounding context).